# Corrupted HDD: lost partitions, shrunken drive, damaged boot sectors, CHS and LBA mismatch

Tags: partitioning, mount, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption, mft

So yesterday I received a "dead" 1TB WDC WD10 JVPX-22JC3T0 laptop HDD from a relative. I never really faced anything like this before, but I tried.

**History:**

It had been used in a Windows machine, with two (possibly 500GB) partitions. The last time it was used it emitted an "unhealthy sound", and the next time Windows tried to boot into recovery mode, which at some point failed (I know this is an undetailed description, but he is not a computer savvy person). All of his important data is on it, and he didn't make any backups.

I tried to mount it with a SATA connection. BIOS showed that it's only a 32MB drive, with an unknown file structure. When I booted the drive often wouldn't show, so from that on I used an external HDD enclosure.
Windows recognized the disk, but needs it to be formatted, **which I did not do** so I would not loose any salvageable data.

**What I tried:**

CHKDSK: first threw a raw disk error, now recognizes it as an NTFS volume of 65536 KB.
TestDisk/Photorec: recognizes the first 32MB, and two identical partitions (same start and end!) and says:

```
Warning: Bad endning cylinder (CHS and LBA don't match)
```

With photorec I see the same - [see attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5kHM.jpg)

DMDA: when I try to load it as a physical drive, it warns me of the following:

```
There are partitions in MBR table which require the disk size to be not less than (bytes) LBA 1.00TB. Current disk size is 65134 LBA (33.0MB). There may be errors in MBR table or driver can't access entire disk (...) .
```

Nevertheless, it finds two volumes whose "structure is absent or damaged"- [see attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyuoI.jpg) I would scan the volumes one-by-one, but the program doesn't allow me as the start and end sectors are out of the boundaries (remember, it sees only 32MBs).

I also tried to mount the disk's voulmes in Linux, but it wouldn't as it is corrupted.

At this point I am out of tools and ideas. I thought of quickformatting the entie disk to get back the full capacity and then run some sort of recovery tool, but first I wanted to ask the community, hopefully somebody is more experienced, than me.

Edit: I've also tried OnTrack EasyRecovery, but it could only salvage broken (4096KB each) mp4 files, which are unusable.

Comment: DON'T FORMAT IT! At least, not until you have abandoned all hope of recovering anything from it. It can only do harm. In Linux `gparted` does a reasonable job of finding partitions on a disc with a damaged MBR: I would expect a similar result to DMDA. You can use use `gparted` or `dd` to make a raw back-up of the entire disc (provided you have enough disc space, compressing on the fly if necessary). Note that `gparted` calls `dd`, but doesn't copy to a file. After that, you can start using recovery tools in anger, because you can always restore the current image and start again.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. If I manage to save the images, where should I go on? With what tools and how do you think could I get some results? Also I should add, only one partition contains important data (probably the one which had windows installed on it), but as of now I can't look into the files. The other partition had films and other, expendable things on it.

Comment: If `gparted` finds a partition, you should be able to mount it with `disks` (you can mount it in `gparted` itself if you create a mount point and add an entry in `/etc/fstab`).

Comment: Ok. I have a really old pc which doesn't "like" booting from USB (and conveniently doesn't have a DVD drive at the moment), so first I'll try from a virtual machine. I hope it still can be done through it.

Comment: I don't think a VM will provide the low-level access that `gparted` requires, though I've never tried it.

Comment: As I explained to the commenter below, I tried saving data with ddrescue to no avail. Booting from SystemRescueCD from an USB in GUI fired up Gparted and after throwing several errors (Can't have partitions outside of disk) it found the two ~500GB partitions, and found one to be the boot NTFS, the other was unknown. Fixing it from the program failed for the same reasons as ddrescue. So, as it seems I first need to restore the original capacity of the HDD and only then can I go on solving the other problems. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: I think your only hope now may be to use a raw disc scanner, which looks for recognisable file patterns. They work reasonably on contiguous files, but without the disc allocation table they don't deal well with fragmentation, as the fragments lack the headers which identify the file type. But if the partition size is wrong you may need to **quick** format first, though not before you have explored all other avenues.

Comment: I see. Well, I'll try to avoid formatting if possible (by the way, windows' formatting is quick format by default,is it?). Do you have any specific program for raw disk scanning?

Comment: I have found Convar's [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1) as good as any I've tried. This is a Windows program and it's freeware.

Comment: Unfortunately this program is useless. But I understand now what you ment - I have tried raw scanning before, but all programs failed. To name some: Zero Assumption Recovery, Find and Mount, Ontrack EasyRecovery, a few Easeus programs, Recuva...all failed at some point or returned useless fragments of data. So should I format now in windows?

Comment: That's not a decision I can take. It is up to you to decide whether there are any other options to explore. I would do everything I could to make a copy of it before I took this irrevocable step, but I have never seen a corruption like you describe. If the data are really valuable, a final step before you format is to discuss whether it is worth paying for a data recovery expert to look at it, but your relative will need to be prepared for a bill of hundreds of pounds/euros/dollars. One thing is sure - he won't fail to back up in the future.

Comment: Do you think there is any other tool that I can use to get back the original size of the disk? Also, you have missed one question: windows' formatting is a quick format?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was rhetorical. The GUI format has a tick-box to select quick format: not sure about the command-line default. It is also possible that the defaults vary between different Windows releases. Having never seen your disc size problem, I have no experience of programs to solve it: I have mainly used `test` and `gparted` for my problems. There are quite a few partition and file recovery tools on [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) that you may want to look at before you take the step of formatting (which may not solve the size problem, you realise).

Comment: I found the solution, using UBCD from a USB, running HDAT2. I'll add the solution to the post. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @P.Zoltan Please don't add answers as part of the question. Rather, post it as a self-answer, and remove it from the question itself. That way, the community is able to vote on it, and you can accept your own answer to indicate the issue has been resolved. See http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Very pleased you sorted it. I used to recommend UBCD4Win, but this was not being maintained, so I settled on Hiren's Boot CD instead, having forgotten about the original UBCD. (Please follow @MichaelKjörling's recommendation - I hadn't realised you had posted your answer.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the heads up, I corrected the post.

Comment: @P.Zoltan You're welcome. It isn't always easy for newcomers to get it right here the first time around, but you seem to be doing quite well. (I see you have a question with the same issue on [so] as well.) I would suggest that you take the [tour] as well as read through the help center sections on asking and answering.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I forgot about that one, but fixed that too. Thank you for being so helpful. I often run into Stack posts but rarely get around asking a question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** 
I downloaded and ran `Ultimate Boot CD` from a USB, which allowed me to run `HDAT2` (32bit program) on a 64bit machine using some sort of DOS environment. `HDAT2` reduced the `HPA` (Host Protected Area) to 0 blocks, restoring the original block size of the disk. This restored the original disk size from 32MB to 1TB. With that done, `Testdisk` wrote the partition table from my rescue Linux Live USB. Booting back to windows, `DMDE` recoginsed the two partitions and an NTFS search recognized the full root. 
I managed to save about 90% of the data that was important.

Answer (score 0):

Find another 1TB disk (target), 
boot from a Linux Rescue CD (*), then 
`$ ddrescue -f -b1M *source-device* *target-device*` 
[(*) for some reason on Ubuntu it is named gddrescue]

Should work for NTFS.

Or read here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42450/advanced-ntfs-partition-file-recovery-techniques-for-damaged-drives-io-errors

Comment: In Ubuntu `gddrescue` is the _package_ name: the command is `ddrescue`, as above.

Comment: I will look into it and keep you posted. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Unfortunately ddrescue won't help. Although I can see the two partitions in fdisk (eg. sdc1, sdc2) the main device (sdc) shows to be much smaller and thus the program throws an error and fails to copy (it can't copy from outside the disk as it sees it as a 32-33MB HDD). I could only copy the first 32-33MBs of data, which is miniscule compared to the real size of 1TB.